# highcharter: how do I make a grouped plot using the hcaes function

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

The plot below makes a stacked column chart in highcharter. I attempted to make this a grouped column chart, but my addition of the stack field fails to achieve the desired result.

```
data = data.frame(player = rep(c('Edwin', 'Ahmad', 'Sonia', 'Jessica'), 2),
              games = c(10, 20, 15, 40, 12, 57, 18, 49),
              win_rate = c(.5, .2, .8, .4, .1, .7, .3, .43),
              week = rep(c(1,2), 4))




highcharter::highchart() %>% 
  highcharter::hc_xAxis(categories = data$player) %>% 
  highcharter::hc_plotOptions(column = list(stacking = 'normal'))  %>%
  highcharter::hc_add_series(data = data %>% dplyr::filter(week == 1), type = 'column', highcharter::hcaes(x = player, y = win_rate, stack = week),
                             dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format='{point.games}')) %>% 
  highcharter::hc_add_series(data = data %>% dplyr::filter(week == 2), type = 'column', highcharter::hcaes(x = player, y = win_rate, stack = week),
                             dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format='{point.games}'))
```

Comment: Did you get your answer? I am asking because below answer is not accepted, your above code is not working in my environment and I am wondering whether you need more help or not.

Comment: Hi yes, I got my answer. I forgot to mark it correctly. I have also added the `highcharter::` and `dplyr::` prefixes as needed so this code should work if you have those packages installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this resemble to what you want?

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = data$player) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = data %>% filter(week == 1), type = 'bar', hcaes(x = player, y = win_rate, group = week),
                dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format='{point.games}')) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = data %>% filter(week == 2), type = 'bar', hcaes(x = player, y = win_rate, group = week),
                dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format='{point.games}'))
```

Comment: Yes, I just need to change "bar" to "column" and it's perfect. I thought I had tried using `group = week`, but I guess not. Thank you!